# WebDriverManager.chromedriver().useBetaVersions().version("73.0.3683.20").setup(); runs Chrome 72

Tags: webdrivermanager-java

In execution logs i see:
"[main] DEBUG io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Driver chromedriver 73.0.3683.20 found in cache"
But when I open in Chrome: Help -> Google Chrome - informations I see that it's 72

Answer (score 1):

`Chromedriver` and `ChromeBrowser` are two seperate things. Chromedriver allows Selenium to control and manage the chrome browser.

WebDriverManager checks the version of the driver (e.g. chromedriver) available on your system. If not found, it uses the latest version of the driver.

From ChromeDriver downloads page (http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads), the latest version is `73.0.3683.20`.
So it seems it has automatically downloaded the latest version of the driver, which is printed in the logs that you see.

Chromedriver 73 supports Chrome Browser v72 so it will work seamlessly